# mgiza compile error

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, giza++

I am trying to install the latest version mgiza++ (0.7.1) on my Ubuntu machine, but I'm getting the following erros. I have installed Boost via running this command: sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

after running ./configure

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for library containing strerror... none required
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/mkcls/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

after running make

```
...
/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward/backward_warning.h:33:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
In file included from StatVar.h:33:0,
                 from Problem.h:34,
                 from KategProblem.h:34,
                 from KategProblemTest.h:30,
                 from KategProblemTest.cpp:27:
myleda.h: In instantiation of ‘B& leda_h_array<A, B>::operator[](const A&) [with A = std::basic_string<char>; B = int]’:
KategProblemTest.cpp:96:18:   required from here
myleda.h:221:5: error: ‘insert’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
myleda.h:221:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘__gnu_cxx::hash_map<std::basic_string<char>, int, my_hash<std::basic_string<char>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> > >, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
myleda.h:221:5: note: use ‘this->insert’ instead
myleda.h: In instantiation of ‘B& leda_h_array<A, B>::operator[](const A&) [with A = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; B = int]’:
KategProblemTest.cpp:265:38:   required from here
myleda.h:221:5: error: ‘insert’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
myleda.h:221:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘__gnu_cxx::hash_map<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >, int, my_hash<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >, std::less<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > > >, std::equal_to<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<int> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
myleda.h:221:5: note: use ‘this->insert’ instead
make[3]: *** [mkcls-KategProblemTest.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Dropbox/senior_thesis/mgizapp/src/mkcls'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Dropbox/senior_thesis/mgizapp/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/Dropbox/senior_thesis/mgizapp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I suspect I'm not linking the Boost library correctly in the Make file. Please let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing line 220 of src/mkcls/myleada.h

Originally:

```
insert(typename MY_HASH_BASE::value_type(a,init));
```

I changed it to:

```
this->insert(typename MY_HASH_BASE::value_type(a,init));
```

Comment: Thanks:) It helped me to solve a similar issue (not in mgiza++).